# How to get the ID from URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC.

I have edit page url like {controller}/Edit/2

so on the **view page** how can I get the ID from this URL?

I'm gonna put a link to redirect to some page with sending above ID.

**EDIT**
Like

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("name", "Action", "Controller", new{ ID = ? } ) %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can get it from the RouteData object

```
 <%=Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the ID in the ViewData in your action method, then your view can access the value from the ViewData.

Controller: `ViewData["ID"] = id;`

View: `<%=Html.ActionLink("name", "Action", "Controller", new{ ID = (int)ViewData["ID"]} ) %>`

Answer (score 0):

...in view you get info in the model to show data so you have id in model then you can get id and pass id easy
 call Model in View :

```
@model IEnumerable<NewsWebsite.Models.Blog>
  foreach (var item in Model)
            {
//your code
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BlogID })

}
```

Or

you can get the id from URL Like This:

Cotroller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    ViewBag.ID = id;
    //Your Code......
    return View(...);
}
```

View:

```
@{  
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
var ID = ViewBag.ID;
}
```

Now you have an ID in the variable

Answer (score -1):

I know of two ways: You can create your link and use the "ViewData" property to pass the link to your view or you can stronglyType the ViewPage.

Here is a link on [strongly typing the view](http://www.squaredroot.com/post/2008/01/07/MVC-Strongly-Type-ViewPages-Without-A-Code-Behind.aspx).

Comment: Not in the controller! but on view page!